# Why this EntityManagerSaveException?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, devforce

I am using Silverlight 4 and DevForce 6.1.11.0

I have some POCO classes that implement EntityAspect.

When changes are saved via EntityManager.SaveChanges; DevForce does not save these POCO entities to the server, because these POCO entities are not part of EF.

Instead I send them to a webservice via WebClient.UploadStringAsync.

This works, expect when I am saving more than one entity of the same type. Then I get this exception:

> EntityManagerSaveException: An entity with this key: PocoMyClass: 0,0
>   already exists in this entityManager

I have checked the cache, and there is no entity with that key.

The WebClient.UploadStringAsync still sends the data and everything gets saved, but the exception does not look good to customers.

How do I work around this exception?

Comment: What PocoSaveMode setting are you using?  Review http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/poco-save-mechanisms to see if you're missing anything required by DevForce.

Comment: I am not setting PocoSaveMode to anything. I have a PocoSaveAdapter and a PocoServiceProvider on the DevForce server, which are used for certain poco types. The poco types that I have problems with are not supposed to go to the DevForce server. Is the round-trip to the DevForce server causing the exception for these poco types?

Answer (score 0):

The poco entities that I am having problems with are only supposed to live on the client, not the DevForce server. The reason is that only the client can access these on the local network.

So I am using WebClient.OpenReadAsync to read the data in and create the poco entities on the client. And then I use WebClient.UploadStringAsync when saving the poco entities.

When creating the poco entity and adding it to the entitymanager, I do like this:

```
var pocoEntity = new PocoMyClass();
pocoEntity.keyId = some integer;
…
entityManager.AddEntity(pocoEntity);
pocoEntity.EntityAspect.AcceptChanges();
```

After doing this I see that the properties for EntityVersion.Original of the poco entity only contains empty stuff (NULL´s and zero’s).

Is this the reason for the exception when saving?

How can I manipulate EntityVersion.Original when the entity does not come from the DevForce server?

Comment: In theory, DevForce shouldn't be sending entities with an Unchanged entity state to the server, but DF does do various cache cloning/processing and the error is likely thrown either when cloning or doing post-processing of the save results into the EM cache.  If you can get a stack trace (with inner exception info) that may help pinpoint the problem.  If not, and you're a licensed DevForce customer, you can send a small repro sample to IdeaBlade support.

Comment: The point is that these entities are changed, but I do not want them sent back to get server.

Comment: Changed entities in the EM cache will automatically be sent to the server.  To avoid this you can import only the changes which should be saved into another EM and call save on that EM.